# JQuery flot within Modal Popup with Tabs does not appear after selecting another modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, flot

Using Visual Studio 2012 with JQuery, Bootstrap, and Flot.

My screen shows multiple items.  When an item is selected, a Modal popup with tabs appears which contains a Flot graph on the first tab.  (Actually there is a getJSON call to get the graphing data, so the graph does not appear until after the tab is populated).

This all works fine when selecting a unique item.  However, when an item that was previously selected is clicked the Flot graph does not appear.

This is what the HTML for the Flot looks like:

```
<div id="rightside-@Model.Room.RoomId" class="rightside">
  <div id="placeholder-@Model.Room.RoomId-container"  style="width:460px;height:300px;margin-bottom:28px">
    <div id="placeholder-@Model.Room.RoomId" style="width:460px;height:250px;margin-bottom:20px"></div>
    <input type="text" name="from" class="input-medium" value="#startDate"  />
    to
    <input type="text" name="to" class="input-medium" value="#endDate"/>
    <input type="button" class="btn" data-function="refine-date" data-value="change_graph_dattes" value="Change dates" style="float:right"/>
  </div>
<div>
```

In stepping through the code I set a breakpoint right before the $.plot statement and I see that the plot space (placeholder-nn), it's parent container (placeholder-nn-container), and the container above that (rightside-nn) all have 0 height, width, left, right, bottom, and top.  However, the rest of the tab and elements within the container (inputs) are appearing properly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this happening while you are switching from tab-to-tab?

Comment: You generally need to reinitialize or force a redraw of these sorts of components whenever they go from hidden to visible.

Comment: `This all works fine when selecting a unique item. However, when an item that was previously selected is clicked the Flot graph does not appear.`  - What does that mean?  Can you create an example fiddle?

Comment: Switching from Tab to Tab works fine.  It is when the modal window hides and then comes back that the divs do not have any position info.

cvrebert--I think I am attempting to redraw the components.  However, they do not have position info so the flot does not redraw.

Comment: I put a little effort into reproducing your situation and failed: http://plnkr.co/edit/1ajiLzoeb2yJaA1YxRG8?p=preview (everything seems ok).  You'll need to reproduce it for further help.

Comment: Mark -- Thank you for this effort.  I have modified your simplistic code and gotten failures, but not the one I have reported here.  I will continue trying to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

After further debugging, I found that at the time the graph was trying to plot the divs within the tab had no size, but the tab itself did.  Thus I reasoned it was something to do with tab activation.

To get this to work, I had to:

1. Disable the automatic activation of the 1st tab
2. Activate the tab via javascript after a short delay (1/10 second)

This statement did not work:

```
$('#tabs a:first').tab('show');
```

Doing this did work:

```
setTimeout(function () { $('#tabs a:first').tab('show'); }, 100);
```